# What is AnonPages part of? Memory questions

Tags: java, memory, garbage-collection, g1gc

I have an app that uses Java 8 and G1GC. I notice large spikes in AnonPages & Eden Generation from /proc/meminfo and can't seem to track it down nor find any info, all I get is "Non-file backed pages mapped into userspace page tables" which is super cryptic. A few questions for clarification:

- Is AnonPages part of the heap? or native memory or something else?
- Is AnonPages linked to the Eden generation somehow?
- Is there a way to troubleshoot anonpages or mitigate a peak of it?
- Separately, is free memory part of allocated memory still? I'm getting allocated, free, commited, and reserved super confused

For additional info, I've tried:

- heap dumps (no real change)
- native memory tracking (same commited & reserved memory)
- it doesn't seem to be a thread leak since it's form one large block of anon page as opposed to a lot of small anon page blocks as I've seen in other questions

I have been STUCK on this issue for the past week and would be incredibly grateful for any help.